# Trying to change attribute on button that launched a modal, when clicking a button in the modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a button with some data attributes. When I click it, a modal is shown. In this modal I have a button that updates DB and closes the modal. I need to change the data attribute in the button I clicked on to show the modal. Anyone have suggestions? See last line of code. e.relatedTarget is not working here.

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal','#myModal', function (e) {
    $('#textareaID').val($(e.relatedTarget).data('text')); //the data attribute used here I need to change later
    $('#listID').val($(e.relatedTarget).data('listid'));
});

$(document).on('hide.bs.modal','#myModal', function (e) {
    //Clearing values before next use of modal
    $('#textareaID').val('');
    $('#listID').val('');
});

$(document).on('click', '#btnSave', function(e) {
    var id      = $('#listID').val();
    var text    = $('#textareaID').val();

    //code here to update DB

    //Now need to set the data-text attribute value to "text" variable.
    $(e.relatedTarget).data('text', text); // NOT WORKING!
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? You don't have the ending `);` on your `#btnSave` click function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work, add a class to the button that opened the modal, then when saving the modal just replace the data-attribute and remove the 'opened' class.

```js
var modal = $('.modal');
var btn = null;
$(document).on('click', '.open-modal', function(e) {
  btn = $(this);
  btn.addClass('opened-modal');
  modal.show();
  modal.find('.modal-header').append('Clicked: ' + $(this).html());
  $(document).on('click', '#btnSave', function(e) {
    var text = $('#myInput').val();

    // code here to update DB

    // Now need to set the data-text attribute value to "text" variable.
    btn.attr('data-text', text);
    btn.removeClass('opened-modal');
    modal.hide();
  });
  $(document).on('click', '#btnClose', function(e) {
    var btn = null;
    modal.hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="open-modal" data-text="button">one</button>
<button class="open-modal" data-text="button">two</button>
<button class="open-modal" data-text="button">three</button>
<button class="open-modal" data-text="button">four</button>
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal</h5>
        <input id="myInput" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id="btnSave" data-dismiss="modal">add-attr</button>
        <button type="button" id="btnClose" data-dismiss="modal">close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well actually it didn't work... I forgot to mention that I have multiple buttons (Table where each row has a button). I need to set the value to only the button that was clicked, not all buttons.

Comment: @JamesT Answer edited, just put the modal save function inside the modal open function, this way we set a variable for the button and can access it inside the modal save.